# Why do multiple threads not go faster in .NET (they do in Java)

Tags: .net, multithreading, ikvm

We have a benchmarking program for our reporting system that generates a specific report 2,000 times.

We have tried to reduce this down to just the time in our engine so:

1. The template is read from disk once into memory, then that copy in
   memory is passed to the engine.
2. File based datasources (XML, JSON) are also read into memory once and then that cached datasource is reused.
3. The SQL database is SqlServer on the same machine. So there is I/O, but it should be fast.
4. The OData datasource is on a different server so this has I/O that can take a bit of time.

Now here's where it gets interesting. Our engine is written in Java and we use IKVM to create a .NET version of it. IKVM creates DLLs that are true .NET clr byte codes. It's as though we wrote the same code in C#. So fundamentally we have the same code on Java & C#.

And the JSON (JPath) Java code is 100% the .NET JSON code via IKVM. The XML (XPath) Java code is 98% the same on the .NET side. The Sql code is seperate on the class to the connector (JDBC vs. ADO.NET) but everything outside of those connectors is identical. Same for OData.

So to sum up, same code and for XML/JSON totally CPU bound, while Sql a bit I/O bound and OData a bit more I/O bound.

Here's the results under Java. Pretty much a 50% increase in total production (each report generates in a single thread, it's the total pages across all reports across all threads we're measuring) for doubling the number of threads.

This is on a 4 core system that with hyper-threading appears as 8 cores to the program.

Java Engine Output (Pages Per Second)
[image]

But in .NET not as expected. XML & JSON small improvement from 2 - 4 threads and nothing after that. Sql decent improvement from 2 - 4 threads and again nothing after that. Only OData shows the expected improvement:

[image]

Our code to run this under multiple threads is:

```
ReportWorker[] workers = new ReportWorker[numThreads];
for (int ind = 0; ind < numThreads; ind++)
    workers[ind] = new ReportWorker(ind, new CommandLine(cmdLine));
System.Threading.Thread[] threads = new System.Threading.Thread[numThreads];
for (int ind = 0; ind < numThreads; ind++)
    threads[ind] = new System.Threading.Thread(workers[ind].DoWork);
for (int ind = 0; ind < numThreads; ind++)
    threads[ind].Name = "Report Worker " + ind;

for (int ind = 0; ind < numThreads; ind++)
    threads[ind].Start();

// we wait
for (int ind = 0; ind < numThreads; ind++)
    threads[ind].Join();
```

When I run for 4 threads all 8 CPUs (using the Windows performance monitor) are sitting between 50% & 80%. When running 8 threads all 8 CPUs are running at 80% - 95%.

Is there something in the above threading code that would cause these results? This is a command line app - is there some reason it might not run the threads simultaneously?

Any suggestions about what to change or investigate are appreciated.

Comment: How is your thread pool configured?

Comment: hard to say with few levels of virtualisation. In Java world google "low latency Java". In short: allocating some count of objects can give significant effect in both env.

Comment: @johnny5 I've done no configuration for the thread pool, I just allocate those Thread objects. Should I? And if so, how?

Comment: @DavidThielen you can up the minimum number of threads, so that you maintain more threads by default for high loads.

Comment: @DavidThielen what version of .Net is this build on 4.5 or before?

Comment: Additionally look at gcServer Configuration, on older versions of .net they didn't run garbage collection [concurrently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcconcurrent-element)

Comment: @johnny5 We're using .NET 4.5.1. As to more threads, is that a setting as to how many threads it allows concurrently? If so, where/how is that set?

Comment: You are *first* going to have to dig into the anomaly you observed, starting 4 threads but seeing 8 cores occupied is good evidence that there is more than either you know or we know.  Well, definitely than we know.  The only thing we *can* see is that this is not a good way to distribute work across cores, that code always takes at least as long as the slowest thread.  Which, if it happens to run on one of the hyper-threaded cores, can be very slow.  Use a concurrency analyzer to get real insight.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/concurrency-visualizer

Comment: That’s setting is the minimum number of threads kept alive in the thread pool, but you may want to use the thread pool instead of spawning those threads

Comment: @HansPassant - Is the code I have for creating the threads ok? Or should I be using a different thread type or have some settings changed? For example, should they be background threads?