# How do I reduce the memory management hit in .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading, ikvm

This is a follow-on question to my question [asking why my code does not multi-thread well in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386143/why-do-multiple-threads-not-go-faster-in-net-they-do-in-java).

I have a CPU intensive console app that is about 30% faster going from 2 threads to 4 and 0% faster going from 4 threads to 8 (4 core system so 8 "cores" with hyperthreading). This same code increases at 50% for each step in Java.

33% of the code time for the 8 thread case is in memory management ([via Concurrency Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/dd997688(v=vs.110))). I dove into it and it's just little hits in the time all over the place, not one big case. And it's where objects are created for short periods, but nothing gigantic.

Is there a way to do something about this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcserver-element

Comment: @HansPassant - that was it - thank you. If you put that as an answer I'm happy to select it.

Comment: I cannot guess what effect that had on your app.  Just share what you discovered in your own answer.